# COOK STOVE INSULATOR

Tags: wood, stove

hello i want to create a stove which uses briquettes or wood for cooking at my remote house which has no access to gas nor electricity. So currently i am looking for an affordable insulator so as to attain less heat loss. Can you suggest any insulator.

Comment: Ceramic is a good insulator but burning inside a house can be dangerous, proper venting would be my concern for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually what you are looking for is likely [Fire Bricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_brick) depending on your location you might be able to get them from lowes, amazon etc.

That being said, all cooking indoors should be done inside a well vented stove, and there are many commercially available wood stoves that allow you to cook on the top easily.